# FineUploader update thumbnail with Ajax request to server (using qq-file-id)

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Since I am using FineUploader to upload non-image documents, I create a thumbnail (preview) on the server and would like to add it to the UI once the upload succeeded.

As my UI features multiple uploads, I need to know what file the preview is to be associated with.

Analyzing the HTML, I saw that each file presented in the UI is represented by an li with the following code:

```
<li class="qq-file-id-0 qq-upload-success" qq-file-id="0"> ... </li>
```

How can I tweak FineUploader to include the value of qq-file-id in the POST request used to upload the file ? In the example above, I would need to pass the value "0".

Note: I am using file chunking, so I see two solutions:

- either pass the value with each chunk upload request
- or pass it with the assemble request at the end

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question if I put provide a hint: look at the setParams API method.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I finally implemented is to add an onComplete callback, since this will provide the FineUploader internal file ID as a parameter. I can then use an Ajax call to change the thumbnail / preview.

1) While initializing FineUploader, define the onComplete callback:

```
$("id").fineUploader({
callbacks: {
    onComplete: function(the_id, name, response, xhr) {
        var elementClass, element;

        // check for errors during the upload process
        try {
            responseHash = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.response);
            errors = responseHash.errors;
            errorText = errors.join();
        }
        catch(err) {
            errorText = "";
        }

        if (errorText.length > 0) {
            // append the error text if there are errors
            elementClass = ".qq-file-id-" + the_id + " .qq-upload-status-text";
            element = $(elementClass);
            element.append("<br />" + errorText);
        } 
        else {
            // the upload was successful since no errors are reported 
            if (responseHash.success) {
                $.ajax( {
                    url:  thumbnailLoadUrl,
                    type: "GET",
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                        qq-file-id-: the_id,
                        // whatever other data is required to update the thumbnail / preview
                    }
                });
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

});

2) in the view (js.erb file):

```
$('<%= "li.qq-file-id-#{@qqfileid} .qq-thumbnail-wrapper" %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(image_tag ...) %>");
```

Comment: No need to parse the response. The `response` parameter passed to `onComplete` contains the response parsed as an object.